# Use of less and lesser vs lesser and lesser

Tags: word-usage

> The consumer on an indifference curve is willing to sacrifice *less and lesser* of good y to get an additional unit of good x.

This is an answer I got from a model answer paper while preparing for economics exam..my question is...is the use of "less and lesser" here, grammatically correct?

Comment: In normal usage, the word **less** means a smaller amount or quantity. The word **lesser** means of reduced value, something which is not as good. So "less apples" means "apples, but not as many", and "lesser apples" means "apples, but of inferior quality."

Comment: @asfallows: Your first sentence is right. Unfortunately your example is not. 'Not as many apples' refers to a smaller *number*, not amount or quantity, and is therefore expressed as *fewer apples*.

Comment: @TimLymington I'm confused by your comment. 'not as many' had the same meaning as 'fewer'. Both phrases are used to refer to a reduction in quantity, number, or amount. I don't understand the distinction you are drawing between number and quantity/amount

Comment: @asfallows: Simply, *fewer* refers to number (so *fewer apples*), while *less* refers to amount (so *put less apple in* in a recipe would refer to a smaller weight of apple puree or chopped apple). **Fewer beer* and **less hours* are both wrong in normal speech.

Comment: Oh, yes, I see your point and I agree; I misunderstood what you were talking about in the earlier comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It is not correct.

> The consumer on an indifference curve is willing to sacrifice less and less of commodity y to get an additional unit of commodity x.

is a better sentence in my opinion

There are no such expressions as *less and lesser* or *lesser and lesser*

The correct expression is less and less.

Also first time I have ever seen goods in singular. [However it does exist in economics it seems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_%28economics%29). Note that the word *good* is not used in the description except once:

> In economics, a ***good*** is a material that satisfies human wants and provides utility, for example, to a consumer making a purchase. A common distinction is made between 'goods' that are tangible property (also called goods) and services, which are non-physical. Commodities may be used as a synonym for economic goods but often refer to marketable raw materials and primary products.

Lastly (before your edit) I would expect ***on*** *an indifference curve*